# Program prints out the same print statement twice

Tags: c, scanf

My program is working fine and everything but I want it to be perfect. So I've stumbled up on this problem that when my function runs, it prints out the same `printf()` statement twice.

Let me show you what I mean, this is how my function looks (skipping main/prototypes)

```
void decision2(struct CardDeck *deck) {
char choice;
int Ess;
printf("\n%s, Your have %d\n", deck->name2, deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
while (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer <= 21)
{
    if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer == 21) {
        printf("You got 21, nice!\n");
        break;
    }
    if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer < 21) {
        printf("Would you like to hit or stand?\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
    if (choice == 'H' || choice == 'h') {
        printf("You wish to hit; here's your card\n");
        Ess = printCards(deck);
        if (Ess == 11 && deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 10)
        {
            Ess = 1;
        }
        deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer += Ess;
        printf("Your total is now %d\n", deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 21) {
            printf("Sorry, you lose\n");
        }
    }
    if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's') {
        printf("You wished to stay\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

}

So the thing in my code thats weird is this part:

```
    if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer < 21) {
        printf("Would you like to hit or stand?\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
```

The output of the program is becoming this:

```
    k, Your have 4
Would you like to hit or stand?
Would you like to hit or stand?
h
You wish to hit; here's your card
6 of Clubs
Your total is now 10
Would you like to hit or stand?
Would you like to hit or stand?
h
You wish to hit; here's your card
King of Diamonds
Your total is now 20
Would you like to hit or stand?
Would you like to hit or stand?
s
You wished to stay
```

As you see, the printf prints the statement twice and I can't figure out the program to be honest, so I hope someone do have a solution and an explanation why this is happening?

Comment: You consume only one character with %c, but to enter it you press ENTER, which is a new character. Either ignore \r and \n or maybe use fgets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is, with

```
 scanf("%c", &choice);
```

it reads the previously stored `newline` (entered into the input buffer by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key after the first input) and performs one more iteration. You should write

```
 scanf(" %c", &choice);  //note the space here
       ^^
```

to avoid the newline.

To elaborate, the leading space before the `%c` ignores *any* number of leading whitespace character(s) [FWIW, a `newline` is a whitespace character] and wait to get a non-whitespace input.

Comment: Had no idea about this, thank you so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

There has to be a space before `%c` in `scanf()`, to clear the previously entered newline `\n`:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

Without the space, `scanf()` will scan the newline and jump to the beginning of the loop again (after skipping the remaining `if` statements), skipping the first `if()`, and print `"Would you like to hit or stand?\n"` a second time.